# Youtube iframe api a.u() is not a function

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am implementing an youtube iframe api in a react app I am running into this error

> www-widgetapi.js:formatted:884 Uncaught TypeError: `a.u` is not a function
>   
> at Ya (www-widgetapi.js:formatted:884)
>   
> at Object.W (www-widgetapi.js:formatted:778)
>   
> at Object.Y [as Player] (www-widgetapi.js:formatted:973)
>   
> at e.value (Video.js:120)
>   
> at window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady (Video.js:74)
>   
> at www-widgetapi.js:formatted:1185
>   
> at www-widgetapi.js:formatted:1189

here is the function

```
loadYoutube(){
 id='74YQWthFz8g'
 var data = {
        height: this.props.height,
        width: this.props.width,
        playerVars: {
            enablejsapi: 1,
            autoplay: 1, //
            controls: 0, //Turn off video controls
            modestbranding: 1, //Turn off Youtube Logo
            rel: 0, //Disable related videos at the end
            showinfo: 0, //Disable diplay of title
            disablekb: 0 //disable the keyboard
        },
        videoId: id,
        events: {
            onReady: function() {
                console.log('ready');
            },
            onStateChange: function() {
                console.log('statechange');
            }
        }
    };
    player = window.YT.Player('ytubeplayer', data);
 }
 window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady= (e)=>{this.loadYoutube()}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. For me, it was solved by doing `player = new YT.Player('ytubeplayer', data)`.

It's a constructor function, so you need to use the `new` keyword.

Hope this solves it for you too.